# What is the recommended view for using tabs in android?

Tags: android, tabs

I'm coming from a C# background where tabs are as simple as adding a TabControl and setting it's contents, but I'm having trouble working out what to do in android.

Apparently the TabHost view is deprecated (and also very confusing to use. It seems you can't create it purely in XML, you need to add java code as well?), but I haven't worked out what the recommended replacement is. Something to do with action bars? They aren't in the Android Studio palette by default however. Or perhaps a ViewPager? That isn't in the palette either, but is that what we're recommended to use?

Answer (score 1):

You need to implement action bar tabs. These links may help you:
http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/actionbar.html
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ActionBar.Tab.html
http://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/lateral.html